# CommandButton produces change event causing two axjax requests

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:inputText>` with a nested `<p:ajax event="change" listener="myValidate">` and a `<p:commandButton actionListener="myValidate" process="@form">`.
The problem is, that the *myValidate* method **is called twice**, because pushing the commandButton first triggers the onChange-Event (when edtiting the text before clicking CommandBt) what then calls the *myValidate* method. After that the *myValidate* is called by the CommandButton actionListener.

How can i prevent the double call?

What I need is:

- call myValidate when leaving inputText after change text
- call myValidate when pushing CommandButton (what is sadly implicit triggering the other one)

thanx for help in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about a custom extended `Validator` ? Do a check in the backing bean and throw a `ValidatorError` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `update` and `process`, the ajax request will be called `onBlur` (when the field loses focus):

```
<p:inputText>
  <p:ajax event="change" listener="myValidate" update="myForm" process="@form">
</p:inputText>
```

But note, if the input loses focus in that way that you click on the command button, than there will be 2 subsequent AJAX calls. It's because the first is triggered by the javascript `onBlur` event, and the second by the `onClick` event on the button. However, **only** in that case (if you go first to the other field, it will work as you expect).

The usual solution is to stick to JSF model and validate the whole form on submitting, not every single field on leaving it.

Comment: Thanks for describing my problem more detailed. Not specifying `update` and `process` like i did, just use the default with `@this`. So nearly same as your code.  Unfortunately I have to validate in both cases in my usecase: when submitting the whole form and when changeing the inputText-field (because this updates some data visible on page).